# Como expor os dados corretamente numa datatable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, relacionamento

Preciso de uma informação relativamente a passar duas tabelas pelo index.
Tenho o seguinte código no controller:

```
public function index(){

    $tabela = capitulo::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate();
    
    $tabela1 = documentacao::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate();

    return view('gestao-documental.index', ['itens' => $tabela, 'itens1' => $tabela1]);

   
}
```

E quero passar os dados das duas tabelas :: Capitulo (ID, capitulo) :: Documentacao(ID, ID_capitulo, Documento, versao)
para a seguinte dataTable

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4">

   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
         <thead>
           @foreach($itens as $item)
                <tr>
                    <th> {{$item->capitulo}} </th>                        
                </tr>                      
            </thead>               
            <tbody>
            @foreach($itens1 as $item1)
            <tr>
                <td> {{$item1->documentacao}} </td>                    
            </tr>
            @endforeach     

            </tbody>
            @endforeach  
        </table>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode postar o código de relacionamentos do modelo eloquente? pq o que precisa é, me parece, um loop dentro de outro, mas é necessário saber quais os dados e relacionamentos para ser efetivo na ajuda

Comment: Alterei um pouco a pergunta. Espero que esteja um pouco mais completa.

Comment: Mas a tabela e tabela1, capítulos e documentação se relacionam no banco? Se sim e vc precisa, por exemplo, colocar cap dentro de doc ou vice-versa, precisa, além de estar correta a modelagem no banco, usar relations em seus modelos para poder recuperar os registros relacionados de um registro "pai" ... consegue adicionar os códigos dos modelos e a modelagem desta parte do banco?

Comment: Estão relacionadas (foreign key). Ou seja a tabela principal (capitulo) é sempre necessaria para criar dados na tabela documentacao. é a unica ligação que as tabelas tem é o ID_documentacao. Não sei se consegui explicar bem .

Comment: então vc precisa adicionar métodos relationship nos modelos e navegar corretamente na Blade, vou colocar um exemplo abaixo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar métodos relationship nos modelos e navegar corretamente na Blade.

Um exemplo para o modelo Capitulo:

```php
<?php
// imports
class Capitulo extends Model
   // configuração do modelo

   public function documentos() {
       // considerando que a modelagem segue os padrões Laravel, senão é necessário passar os parâmetros de chave estrangeira corretamente
      return $this->hasMany(Documentacao::class);
   }
```

No seu controlador

```php
public function index(){

    $capitulos = Capitulo::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate();
    
    return view('gestao-documental.index', compact('capitulos'));
   
}
```

Na visão em Blade

```html
<div class="card shadow mb-4">

   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
         <thead>
           @foreach($cpaitulos as $cap)
                <tr>
                    <th> {{$cap->capitulo}} </th>                        
                </tr>                      
            </thead>               
            <tbody>
               @foreach($cap->documentos as $doc)
                  <tr>
                     <td> {{$doc->documentacao}} </td>                    
                  </tr>
               @endforeach     
            </tbody>
            @endforeach  
        </table>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Acredito que isto lhe ajude a direcionar a solução